# Can't show image with opencv, could not connect to display

Tags: qt, opencv, ubuntu, plugins

I'm running local python script where I try to read an image and show it on my screen. Instead of opening the image I get an error every time. This is how I read and display the image with opencv:

```
image = cv2.imread("images/jp.png")
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/username/.venv/pyimage/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc.
```

Running with `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` gives me a mile long report where are lots and lots of objects like these (just to show a few):

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/zipnote"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/usr/bin/zipnote'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/zipsplit"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/usr/bin/zipsplit'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/zjsdecode"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/usr/bin/zjsdecode'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/zless"
QElfParser: '/usr/bin/zless' is not an ELF object
"'/usr/bin/zless' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/zmore"
QElfParser: '/usr/bin/zmore' is not an ELF object
"'/usr/bin/zmore' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/znew"
QElfParser: '/usr/bin/znew' is not an ELF object
"'/usr/bin/znew' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
```

Comment: Coming from the very same problem, in my case the issue was just about my IDE (*vs code*) that had the `DISPLAY` environment var set to nothing for some reasons. Running the application in the default terminal works as expected.